# How to alter the default facebook page description/title/image when sharing a page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know this sort of stuff can be done through setting up a FB app and configuring opengraph but for my purposes it seems like a lot of overkill for what I actually need.

When someone clicks the standard share link on my page, id just like to specify the content that is displayed in the description and title boxes and if possible specify which image is used.

Id hope to put a line of dynamic content into the description also.

My first thought was to just change the first paragraph of my page so that FB uses this when sharing, however there seems to be some kind of caching happening with this on their end so this would not work for dynamic content.

Any ideas? Or am i just going to have to bite the bullet and spend a few days learning opengraph?

**generic fb like/share module im using**

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1636640659907661',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.4'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i may have found an easy solution here.. possibly just missed it when i was trawling through the FB developer resources (there are a lot!)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices

seems to be tags you can set up on a page for FB to pick up like:

```
Title
A clear title without branding or mentioning the domain itself.

<meta property="og:title"
content="Workday Sets Price Range for I.P.O." />
```